# Is Klein bottle an algebraic variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, klein-bottle

Is Klein bottle an algebraic variety? I guess no, but how to prove. How about other unorientable mainfolds?

If we change to Zariski topology, which mainfold can be an algebraic variety?

Comment: The real projective plane is algebraic and non-orientable.

Comment: What do you mean by "we change to Zariski topology" given a manifold?

Comment: Your question is imprecise. There are at least two versions of it: "is there a _complex_ algebraic variety which is homeomorphic to the Klein bottle when given the analytic topology?" and "is there a _real_ algebraic variety which is homeomorphic to the Klein bottle when given the analytic topology?".

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: Oh, it is for real. In fact, I do not think so much. When I hear a professor teaching topology says that a circle is a algebraic variety, I want to check other interesting pictures.

Answer (score 7):

Any complex manifold is not merely an orientable manifold but an *oriented* manifold. Hence the Klein bottle cannot be a complex manifold (and so not complex algebraic).

Indeed, consider the holomorphic tangent bundle $T M$ of a complex manifold $M$. We define an orientation as follows: take a complex basis $e_1, \ldots, e_n$, and declare the *real* basis $e_1, \ldots, e_n, i e_1, \ldots, i e_n$ to be positively oriented. One can check that this is independent of the choice of complex basis, so this defines a global orientation of $M$.

Comment: A new question: can we define a complex orientation for the complex manifold (or a subset of it) such that the complex projective space for complex orientation is the similar with the real projective space for the real manifold. Maybe we can choose the nonzero holomorphic volume form to do this job.

Answer (score 6):

In the introduction (second page) of [this paper](http://www.mathematik.uni-bielefeld.de/documenta/vol-12/17.pdf) of Biswas and Huisman, it is explained that any non-orientable compact topological surface $X$ is real algebraic (*i.e.* there exists a real smooth algebraic surface $S$ whose real points $S(\mathbb R)$ endowed with the natural differential structure is diffeomorphic to $X$).

In the case of Klein bottle, the corresponding algebraic surface is simply the blowup of $\mathbb P^2(\mathbb R)$ along a real point (I don't know topology enough to see why this is true). They also prove this algebraic surface is unique (*in some sense*, because blowing-up further a non-real point doesn't change the real points but change the algebraic surface).

Comment: Do you mean "any non-orientable compact topological *surface* $X$" ?

Comment: @AndreaMori: absolutely. Thanks!